# How to use the selected audio file using javascript, via <audio> tag in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

How do I deploy a selected audio file using JavaScript via the `<audio>` tag in HTML5?
My code is like this:

```
<audio controls id="audio1">
    <source  src="" type="audio/ogg">
<source  src="" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I don't want to give `src` manually. Instead, I want to set it dynamically via JavaScript.

In JavaScript, for selecting the `src` from files:

```
document.querySelector('#fileSelect').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       // Use the native click() of the file input.
     audio.src = document.querySelector('#fileElem').click();
}, false);
```

I'd welcome any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: thanks guypursey! and mariozski here, I want to change the src attribute of audio-tag by using the javascript. In javascript i am selecting the audio sound track that track i want to play in HTML audio-tag. Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a tag  why don't you just create an object Audio and do something like this :

```
var som = new Audio();
som.src = "powerup.mp3";
som.load();
```

and after `audio.readyState >= audio.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA` 
you can call `som.play();`

This is a sample that wrote some time ago for a game framework : https://github.com/hamilton-lima/vaca5/blob/master/lib/audio.js

Comment: hamilton I looked your code, it's nice & for game purpose. I tried your suggestion but it won't work & couldn't fetch the selected file input to the <audio> tag source dynamically by using js.

Comment: I wasn't able to use the the <audio> tag neither ... only worked for me create the audio object, using new Audio().

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve. But to set source for audio you do as you've posted:

```
var element = document.getElementById('audio');
if (element.canPlayType('audio/wav')) {
  element.src = "link";
} else if (element.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')) {
  element.src = "link";
} else {
   alert('Your browser does not support wav/mpeg audio.');
}
```

Is it not working? What's exactly the problem? Maybe prepare some fiddle to get closer look what are you trying to achieve.